# check if oracle function value given as a parameter exist in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-function

My table looks like this

```
Teacher(ID, Name, Surname)
```

I want to give the user an output.

In case the id given as parameter to the function does not exist in the ID column in the table.

How can I handle this inside a function and give an output:
"The id asked is not present in the table"

```
Create or replace function subjects
(
 code_value  IN Teacher.ID % TYPE
)

RETURN NUMBER

IS
id_value NUMBER

BEGIN

SELECT id 
INTO id_value
FROM TEACHER
WHERE ID = code_value

END

END subjects;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a function you wrote, you can not - it returns a `NUMBER` while the result you want is a string (`VARCHAR2`).

There is a way - to write an exception handler which will be executed when `select` you wrote doesn't return anything as it'll raise `NO_DATA_FOUND`, so:

```
begin
  select ...

exception
  when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'The id asked is not present in the table');
end;
```

This will cause your program to stop (an error is raised, right?) so - if you want to move on, either

- change return datatype or
- switch to a procedure which will have an `OUT` parameter (or two - one for the ID, another for possible error message). Its (procedure's) drawback is that you can't use it in `SELECT` statements but you'll need a piece of PL/SQL code.